# RAISERROR with >20 Severity and Database Permissions

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, database-permissions, raiserror

I'm attempting to deploy an INSTEAD OF trigger to a Sql Azure db. Among other things, it can potentially execute the following line:

```
raiserror('error text', 20, 1, @somevar) with log;
```

Anything with a severity greater than or equal to 20 in Sql Server requires the 'with log' command, which requires ALTER TRACE permissions. Okay, no problem, except I can't figure out how to grant my Sql Azure user the permissions to run it. sp_addrolemember isn't supported in Sql Azure, and the following:

```
grant alter trace to MyUser
```

Fails with this obscure message:

> Msg 40520, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Googling for the above error pulled up very little, and MSDN's [documentation on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336226.aspx) is pretty vague.

Comment: Okay, I was able to get it to work by setting the severity to 18. Still throws a manageable error I can handle in Entity Framework (a DBUpdateException), but doesn't require "with log", and therefore no ALTER TRACE permissions. Still, I'd like to know how to grant permissions like this to Sql Azure.